# Word meaning something terrible or terribly bad

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, vocabulary, diction

I swear I've seen a word like this before, meaning something terrible or terribly bad, used in a sentence like "...resulted in such [plural form] as (bad thing 1) and (bad thing 2)"

I can't remember what the word is, the most reasonable spelling or the cloest I can think of is "horridity/horridities", which isn't even a real word lol. I feel like the root of the word is horror/terror or something similar, but I'm not sure

Comment: *Horror* isn't just an emotion; it's also something which is horrible. You could fit *horrors* into your sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Atrocity**
> [uh-tros-i-tee]
> /noun
>
> 1. the quality or state of being atrocious.
> 2. an atrocious act, thing, or circumstance.
>
> Plural: atrocities
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/atrocity)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the word **atrocity** to imply something terribly bad.

Example: "The war/conflict resulted in such **atrocities** (plural noun) as massacres (bad action 1) and enslavement (bad action 2).

The bad action words in the example can be substituted with other words indicating any form of atrocity.

OED example: ‘Some of them also said they had been forced to witness or commit atrocities, including rape and murder.’

Source: [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/atrocity)

Comment: That is not [the OED](http://www.oed.com)!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for **Horrendous**?

[Merriam-Webster link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/horrendous)

Comment: Please quote the relevant definition here.